# How do I determine the largest value number in a String?

Tags: java, string, return-value

Consider the following String:

```
String test= "0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 241";
```

The largest value is the last value, `241`.  How do I get the count, `15`, of this number within the String, as 241 is the 15th number in the String, and the largest number in the row?

Second example:

```
String test=  "0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 30, 5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5";
```

The result should be 9 as 30 is the largest number and in the 9th place in the String.

Comment: Where is your code? Have you tried any solutions yet? What were the results?

Comment: @user1393500 we are not algorithm writers. Please show what you thinked about logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following example, the `maxIndex` variable will contain the index of the highest value in the array and the actual position will be `maxIndex + 1`, which is what you are looking for.

```
String test = "0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 241";
String[] testArray = test.split(", ");

int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, maxIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
     if (Integer.parseInt(testArray[i]) > max) {
         max = Integer.parseInt(testArray[i]);
         maxIndex = i;
     }
}
```

Edit: initialized the other variables, and corrected some code thanks to comments

Comment: What is counter ? And it should be inferior than `testArray.length` not `testArray.length - 1`. And your if condition won't compile. You can't test a String > than an int. Please read your answer before posting it.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing out the errors on the quickie code reply. x3

Answer (score 5):

split the string with `String.split(",");` it will return an array. Look for the max inside that array

Answer (score 0):

You should split this string with `,`, then find the biggest one in an array. You will get the biggest number string that can be applied to find in given string.

Answer (score 0):

try splitting your string into an array like this,Then find the largest number postion from that array

```
    String[] YourArray=this.split(",");

    int largest = YourArray[0];
int largestpos;

      for(i = 0; i < YourArray.length; i++){

       if(Integer.parseint(YourArray[i]) > largest){
       largest = YourArray[i];
       largestpos=i;// This is what you need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You split your string and put it into an array (of int type)
2) Then you can use any kind of Sorting provided by JAVA API(s).
3) You will find your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and ugly:

```
String initialString = "0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 241";
        String[] sArray = initialString.split(", ");
        List<Integer> iList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String s: sArray) {
            iList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }
        Collections.sort(iList);
        // finding last item's value
        System.out.println(iList.get(iList.size() - 1));
        // now finding index
        System.out.println(iList.indexOf(Integer.parseInt("241")));
```

Output:

```
241
14
```

The second output gives you the index of the largest Integer parsed. 
Note: not checking for `NumberFormatException` here for simplicity.

Better solution:

Still use `String.split` and a `List`, but implement your own `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, pos=0, i=0;
for (String s : test.split(",")) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(s) > max) { max = Integer.parseInt(s); pos = i; }
    ++i;
}
System.out.println("Position of max value is: " + (pos+1));
```